# IBM DB2 looking to get a unique count of each duplicate item in a table and list it with another value of the table

Tags: sql, db2

i have a DB2 table (orderitems) that has columns named ORDERITEMS_ID and ORDERS_ID I'm looking to get a count of all of the orderitems_id that are associated with each orders_id. I can get the count but i would like the order_id associated with that count.

i've tried

```
SELECT COUNT(orderitems_id) as total 
FROM orderitems 
GROUP BY orders_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

i believe this is giving me the total count of each of the items in a order_id. but i'm not sure how to add the order_id with the result set

if i try the following

```
SELECT orders_id, COUNT(orderitems_id) as total 
FROM orderitems 
GROUP BY orders_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

this is a bad query

i've looked into joining but that seems to be dealing with two tables...not sure how to append this information.

Comment: 'bad query' _how_?  Does it fail?  I would have thought that was exactly what you wanted.  Do you have a 'quantity' column in `orderitems` (if ordering multiple of the same item)?  At which point you'd probably want `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`.  Do you want the total, regardless of whether or not the order is associated with any items?  At which point you'd need a `LEFT JOIN`.  Providing sample data and desired results will allow us to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct orders_id, 
       count(orderitems_id) as total 
from orderitems 
group by orders_id 
order by total desc
```

Summarizing precisely what you want to do often helps. In this case, you want a count of `orderitems_id` for each distinct `orders_id`, e.g. for each different value of `orders_id` and not for each line. When you want a result depending on the different values of a column, think `distinct`.

Comment: Except he's using `GROUP BY orders_id` (which he has to use because of the aggregate function), so the results are _already_ 'distinct'.  You're not supposed to mix `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` (usually); The results will not be any different.  How does this answer his query?

Comment: That query will not produce anything different than the "bad query" in the question.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: really? `select distinct a, sum(b) ... group by a` seems a classic to me, and seems also to fit perfectly nate_weldon's need. It would be better if we got some feedback, though...

Comment: Yes, he's accepted this as the answer, but the results won't be any different than the 'bad' query: `GROUP BY a` will result in "for every distinct 'a', do these aggregates", meaning the results will _already_ be distinct.  I can't recall exactly, but I _think_ the optimizer _may_ resolve them to the same operation.  I'll grant that it's often placed in some 'classic' tutorials, but there's no point to it.  Often (but not always), I feel that use of `DISTINCT` is indicative of someone wanting unique results, without any idea of where duplicates are coming from (or how to eliminate them).

Comment: running the query with the distinct or with out the distinct returns the same result